# How to make a control like OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I was wondering how can I make a custom control which after draging from toolbox is placed not in the form but below (sth like openfileDialog control or ToolTipControler). Is this a normal control or this is some kind of special control ? Is it possible to achieve this behaviour ?

Answer (score 3):

Inherit your class from Component, not from Control

Comment: @mastamic Try asking that in a new question, not in a comment.